# Javascript nested if

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone I'm trying to do when an option button selected an other option button appears. It works but when the other option button is selected I wanna display text but it does not work here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".select-box").change(function() {
          if ($(".select-box option[value='3']").attr('selected')) {
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<select class='select-box'><option value='4'>a</option><option value='5'>b</option></select>";
          if ($(".select-box option[value='5']").attr('selected')) {
          document.write("Hello")
          }
          }

        }); 

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select class="select-box">
      <option>Select an option</option>
      <option value="1">no alert</option>
      <option value="2">no alert too</option>
      <option value="3">alert</option>
    </select> 
    <p></br>
    <div id="demo"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use a current version of jQuery.
- Yes, you should not nest your `if`-statements
- The `option` element never will have a "`selected`" attribute. No attributes change when you select something, only properties of the DOM object. Use `.prop()` instead.
- Don't check for the selectedness of `option` elements at all (unless you have a multi-select), just use the `value` property of the `select` element (`.val()` with jQuery).
- Don't use `document.write`. As soon as the document is loaded (fully parsed), this will overwrite the current document with a fresh new one. And your code *is* executed on DOMready, even on a user event.
- As soon the first condition is matched, you want to change your formular. This is OK, but you can't expect the new form to have already some values selected - you again will need to hook on a `change` event